# Optidef package latex specify supremum instead of maximize

Tags: optidef

I am trying to create an optimzation problem which looks like this:

[image]

I use Optidef for all my optimization problems but should I be using regular align environment for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `\underset` macro from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$ \underset{y\geq0}{\sup\psi(y)} $
\end{document}
```

No need for `align` or the like.

[image]